# live search not giving proper results

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Trying to get my live search to work 'properly'.  When I enter an 'a' I get 'aussie' and 'australian' (not sure where these are coming from as they are not in my db) in a area below the box (like a drop down).  I can select one of them and it populates the text box.  The code suggested to me uses mysqli which I am not familiar with.  When I add a typical SELECT statement I am use to I see the correct data (more or less) but it is not selectable.  The reason I say more or less is an 'a' gives me 'aussie' and 'australian' like before (in a drop down).  Adding a 'n' (i.e. searching for 'an') gives me list of all names in my database that contain the string in a DIV but not selectable.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#faq_search_input").keyup(function() {
                var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
                var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;

                if(faq_search_input.length>1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "ajax-search.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(server_response) {
                            document.getElementById("searchresultdata").style.display = "block";
                            $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
                        }
                    });
                } return false;
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="searchholder">
       <input  name="query" class="quicksearch" type="text" id="faq_search_input" />
       <div id="searchresultdata" class="searchresults" style="display:none;"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax-search.php

```
<?php
    //you must define your database settings
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_NAME", "mydb");
    if(isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
        $search = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if ($search->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $search->connect_errno . ") " .     $search->connect_error;
            $search->close();
        }
        $keyword =  trim($_GET['keyword']) ;

        //original statement
        //$query ="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ".DB_NAME.".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";

        //my edited statement
        //$query ="SELECT name FROM ".DB_NAME.".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";

        //basic sql statement
        $query ="SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";

        $values = $search->query($query);
        if( $search->error ) exit( $search->error ); 

        if($values->num_rows != 0) {
            while($row = $values->fetch_assoc()) { 
                echo $row['name']."<br>";
            } 
        }
        else {
            echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
        }
    }
?>
```

database contains a table of user data called users with a column called name.
Any thoughts?

Comment: @ROYFinley - here is what I have.  Any ideas?

Comment: Note:  The aussie and australian only show up in Chrome.  IE and FF do not display this.  The rest of the functionality is the same and you cannot select anything in the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used solution found in the tutorial here
http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete